# Is google app engine 1.6.4 slower in local?

Tags: java, performance, google-app-engine, gwt

**Original issue**

Since I changed the version from 1.6.3. to 1.6.4 I get serious performance problems working together with GWT in hosted mode.

**Update 18/04/2012**

The issue is reproductible also in 1.6.4.1 in dev environment.
By now the best is to downgrade to 1.6.3

**Update 09/07/2012**

According to Kris Giesing:
This is still not fixed in 1.7.0. A request that takes 330ms to process in 1.4.3, and 415ms to process in 1.6.3, takes 13740ms to process in 1.7.0. That's from timing the Java analysis code (no I/O) - almost a 40x slowdown.

**Update 09/08/2012**

Google acknowledged the problem in the [issue 7282](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=7282) of google appengine's public issue list.

Comment: I have noticed it too, certain parts of my code runs several times slower. I noticed while debugging that for basically every method call or class instantiation, one steps into something like Runtime.checkRestricted and such, which doesnt happen in earlier versions. I havent tested 1.6.4 in the cloud so I dont know if it just is the local server that has the problem. My theory now is that they introduced some kind of checks for restricted code/classes/methods to prevent stuff that isnt supported online. But thats a wild guess. Would be interesting to know the online performance though.

Comment: Mind you, I don't use GWT but plain JSP and twig-persist for object persistence

Comment: I use Spring and Objectify, the GWT bottle neck is the RPC implementations which is in the server side. The whole thing makes everything go slow. I downgraded to the 1.6.3.

Comment: Ticket fixed:
Comment 2 by project member tmat...@google.com, Today (10 hours ago)
It should be fixed with 1.6.4.1.

Comment: This is still not fixed in 1.7.0. A request that takes 330ms to process in 1.4.3, and 415ms to process in 1.6.3, takes 13740ms to process in 1.7.0. That's from timing the Java analysis code (no I/O) -  almost a 40x slowdown.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a confirmed performance regression in 1.6.4. We (Google) are putting together a patch that contains a fix and we'll make it available as soon as we can.

Sorry for the trouble

(I'm the guy who introduced the regression)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the info. Any update? for mere curiosity, how long does a fix take since it is coded until it gets to the realease?

Comment: Apparently is broken again in 1.7.0. See the comment in the question. Do you have any info on that ?

Comment: Hi Max, thanks for clearing it up. I have one crucial question though, does the regression only applies to apps running locally in the dev server, or does it also occurs in apps that we deploy to App Engine?

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, something is definitely wrong:
http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=7282

> 1.6.4 starts up extremely slow and takes an abnormal long amount of time to process each request.

Star it!

Answer (score 2):

Even after the sdk 1.6.4.1... its still to slow!

The problem is to process the request, take too long. I cant test with real data anymore, because it is too slow.

Does anyone agree?

When i try to do a batch delete (pm.deletePersistentAll(ltToBeDelete);) of 50 entity, its took me 10 seconds.

Sorry, i'll have to downgrade to the 1.6.3 SDK.. too sad :(

Comment: in my local version the makepersist function takes about 10s to actually complete, AFTER the transaction is complete...

Comment: @johnvdenley i'm using the sdk 1.8.5 and i don't have this problem anymore... Which version did you use?